# Bash shell script isn't looping correctly

Tags: bash, loops

I have written a while...do.. loop; however, the script appears to only loop through one of the functions.

I have a .txt file containing a list of species (each species name on a new line). I tried to write a loop that would read the text file line by line, echo the species name, perform a websearch using ddgr then wait for 30 seconds before repeating the action with the next line.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="species-list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line";
   ddgr --json "$line" >>ddgr-output.json;
   sleep 30;
done<"$file"
```

The script will echo the first species name on the list but then performs the ddgr function on every species name without sleeping or repeating the echo.

Comment: What you're implying should be impossible. You could test it by echoing the ddgr command entirely to be sure.

Comment: I changed the script to just write the ddgr output to the terminal and I could see that it was processing all of the species without a pause.

Comment: Can you try `ddgr --json "$line" </dev/null >>ddgr-output.json;` ? Or `exec 10<"$file"; while IFS= read -u10 -r line` ? Thet's probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376166/execute-a-command-on-remote-hosts-via-ssh-from-inside-a-bash-script).

Comment: @KamilCuk the </dev/null worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the `ddgr` process get's the same standard input, as the whole `while read` loop. The `ddgr` process then reads everything from the standard input, beeing the `<species-list.txt` file.

You can:

- open another file descriptor specific to `read` command inside while, using `exec 1<"$file"` and then tell `read` to read from 10th file descrtiptor `while IFS= read -u10 -r line`
- or you can redirect standard input to `ddgr` command from somewhere else, probably `/dev/null`, so it doesn't eat anything from `species-list.txt`, ex. `ddgr .. </dev/null >>ddgr-output.json`.

Also your script could be just this using `xargs`:

```
< species-list.txt xargs -d'\n' -n1 ddgr --json >> ddgr-output.json`
```